# Replace the attribute rel with class using jQuery - change also the value

Tags: jquery

How can I replace the attribute `rel` with a `class` using jQuery, the value should also be changed. So i just want to delete all `rel` in a `href` and replace it with a `class` attribute, but only within a certain `div` and only when it contains a image?

**For example:**

```
<div class="box">
   <a href="#" rel="lightbox123">
      <img src="#">
   </a>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="box">
   <a href="#" class="lightbox">
      <img src="#">
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".box a:first-child"). removeAttr("rel");` will remove your `rel` attribute.
`$(".box a:first-child").addClass("lightbox");` will add class.

Comment: @OmSao I think you should replace `$(".box")` with `$(".box a img").parent()` to get the desired outcome.

Comment: @EvilDevil: Thanks Mate, Just now did !!

Comment: Thank you very much EvilDevil and OmSao, that worked very well :-)

Comment: @hippolas_cage: If you are satisfied with the answer, Please accept it and close the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try what I mentioned in comment, In the page you can `inspect element` and check that the class is added to show text in `red` color:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <style>
    .lightbox{color: red;}
   </style>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var getTagName = $(".box a:has(img)").parent();  //returns DIV, as $(".box a:has(img)") returns ANCHOR tag

       //$(".box a:first-child").removeAttr("rel"); //this will remove rel attribute from first child of box class without checking if anchor tag has child as img, hence not good.
       //$(".box a:first-child").addClass("lightbox"); // this will add class to the first child without checking img tag, hence not recommendable
         if(getTagName.prop("tagName")=="DIV") //Note that tagName returned in CAPS
         {
           $(".box a:has(img)").removeAttr("rel").addClass("lightbox");// This removes rel attribute
         }

     });
    </script>
  </head>
<body>

<div class="box">
   <a href="#" rel="lightbox123">
      <img src="#" alt="alternate text">
   </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP said, `i just want to delete all rel in a href and replace it with a class attribute` You are removing rel and not setting that value as class. You are adding a new class.

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```js
$(".box a:has(img)").attr("class", function(){
   var val = $(this).attr("rel");
   $(this).removeAttr("rel");
   return val; 
});
console.log($(".box")[0].outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
   <a href="#" rel="lightbox123">
      <img src="#">
   </a>
</div>
```